# Minimo de valores y columnas en grafica morris js

Tags: script

Tengo un inconveninete con respecto al codigo que estoy manejando con Morris.js: https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/

Bueno les comento, tengo un prototipo en arduino que me envia datos de temperatura y humedad cada 6 minutos y estos se alamacenan en una base de datos. Realizo el codigo para visualizar estos datos en una grafica de linea de Morris js.

El problema consiste en que cada vez que se agrega un dato a la Base de datos, ese se visualiza en la grafica pero se van acumulando y no hay un limite de columnas o valores que visualizar. Por ejemplo el prototipo lleva 5 dias enviando datos, entonces en la grafica se muestran todos los datos de esos 5 dias. Ami me gustaria que solamente se visualizaran los datos de los ultimos dos dias.

[image: Grafica]

**Adjunto codigo de la grafica**

```js
<script>
 
 var line = new Morris.Line({
    element          : 'line-chart-informes',
    resize           : true,
    data             : [

    <?php 

    if($noRepetirDatos != null){
 foreach ($noRepetirDatos as $key) {
   echo "{ y: '".$key."', temperatura: ".$nuevaTemperatura[$key]." },";
 }
   echo "{ y: '".$key."', temperatura: ".$nuevaTemperatura[$key]." }";
 }else{
   echo "{ y: '0', temperatura: '0' }";
 }

    ?>

    ],
    xkey             : 'y',
    ykeys            : ['temperatura'],
    labels           : ['temperatura'],
    lineColors       : ['#efefef'],
    lineWidth        : 2,
    hideHover        : 'auto',
    gridTextColor    : '#fff',
    gridStrokeWidth  : 0.4,
    pointSize        : 4,
    pointStrokeColors: ['#efefef'],
    gridLineColor    : '#efefef',
    gridTextFamily   : 'Open Sans',
    gridTextSize     : 10,
    ymax             : 'auto',
    ymin             : 'auto',
    xmax             : 'auto',
    xmin             : 'auto'
  });

</script>
```

**Quedo inmensamente agradecido si me pudiesen colaborar con este problema. Muchas Gracias!**

Comment: que tal si en tu query agregas un `WHERE date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )` para que solo muestre los 2 ultimos dias apartir de la fecha actual? si te es mas facil hasta agregando un campo hora en formato `unix` y solo seria  `(horaunix - 172800)  between max(horaunix)` que seria `60*60*48`

Comment: Bryro, vale compañero, voy a probar la sugerencia que me dice y le cuento que tal me fue. Gracias!

Comment: Byro, probe la solucion que me brindaste pero no me funciono. Segui investigando y la solucion es que tenia que colocar en el query **`LIMIT 20`** el cual me otorga colocar el numero limite de valores en la grafica. De igual manera muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compañeros, les comento que la solucion fue solamente agregar en el Query

`LIMIT 20`

donde (20) Representa el numero de valores maximos que se pueden visualizar en la grafica.

Saludos

Comment: por lo menos leiste tu propia pregunta?? cada 6 minutos!  `6*20 = 2 horas` tu pediste `2 dias!` fuera de que con `limit 20` solo llamas los primeros 20 resultados osea que no va a cambiar jamas esa grafica deberias ser `ORDER BY id DESC limit 20` para que sean los ultimos 20.. replante a tu logica lo estas haciendo mal...

Comment: Si Bryro, entiendo lo que me comenta y en efecto lo tengo de esa manera **`"SELECT * FROM $tabla ORDER BY id DESC limit 240"`** A demas tengo un dataPicker el cual selecciono la fecha que deseo y me muestra en la grafica los valores solicitados.  

Haber me explico, se envia un dato cada 6 minutos, el cual dan 120 datos en un dia, yo queria que cuando se cargara la pagina se mostraran en la grafica los datos de dos dias, osea 240 datos, ya que me estaba mostrando los datos de 5 dias. Y me funciono con **`LIMIT`**. Quizas no me hice entender muy bien en la pregunta ... Ups!